# Can I layer content in a bootstrap 3 grid column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to put a stack of divs inside a single Bootstrap 3 column.

Specifically I want to layer a loading progress gif image on top of the image that is being loaded.

However simply placing the image tags inside a Bootstrap column and setting the CSS z-order doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<div class="col-xs-4 left">Left Col</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 imageholder">
  <img class="center-block" src="http://paulsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/public/lgspinner.gif" width="40px" height="40px" style="z-index:999"/>
  <img class="center-block" src="http://paulsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/public/yeoman.png"     style="z-index:-1"/>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 right">Right Col</div>
```

Plunk :  http://plnkr.co/8T7hyb900g3d4z9IO6Ta

Is there a way to achieve this and retain responsive behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `absolute` positioning for `<img>` tags

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to use what you suggested. All the docs say that position:relative should work, but I couldn't get it to work. I didn't realise absolute was relative to its parent, so I could use it.